# Bootstrap - Floating action button menu size and shadow

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-material-design

I am building an app with Bootstrap 3.3 and [Bootstrap Material Design framework](http://fezvrasta.github.io/bootstrap-material-design/bootstrap-elements.html). I am trying to make a floating action button that opens when you click it.

In an attempt to do this, I've created this [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/w64LRXDoZZ), which has the following code:

```
<div class="btn-group dropup floating-action-button">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-fab btn-raised dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><i class="material-icons">save</i></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" style="min-width:0; background-color:transparent;">
        <li><a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-fab btn-raised"><i class="material-icons">clear</i></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The buttons works, but it doesn't look right. There are two issues that are driving me nuts. First, the popup menu isn't transparent. There is like a `border` and shadow that I can't seem to get rid of.

Second, I can't use the small version of the buttons as shown in the **Floating action buttons** section of the [Bootstrap Material Design framework](http://fezvrasta.github.io/bootstrap-material-design/bootstrap-elements.html) page. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: It looks to me like it's not picking up the material-icons class. I inspected the round Floating Action Buttons on the Bootstrap Material Design framework page and it looks like that specific class is determining those icons and rounding of the buttons.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So the `.dropdown-menu` in bootstrap CSS has by default `box-shadow` and `border`, which you have to reset it in order to make it transparent.

Plus in your Bootply it's not applying the Material Design Icons, because you didn't link the fonts.

Regarding small icons, add `.btn-group-sm` to `.btn-group`

Here is a working **SNIPPET** with examples for every sizes.

```css
.floating-action-button {
  position: relative;
  top: 100px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}
ul.dropdown-menu {
  box-shadow: none;
  border: 0;
  min-width:0;
  background:transparent
}
```

```html
<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Material Design fonts -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700" type="text/css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- Code -->
<div class="btn-group btn-group-lg dropup floating-action-button">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-fab btn-raised dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><i class="material-icons">save</i>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
    <li><a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-fab btn-raised"><i class="material-icons">clear</i></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div><div class="btn-group dropup floating-action-button">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-fab btn-raised dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><i class="material-icons">save</i>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
    <li><a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-fab btn-raised"><i class="material-icons">clear</i></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="btn-group btn-group-sm dropup floating-action-button">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-fab btn-raised dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><i class="material-icons">save</i>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
    <li><a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-fab btn-raised"><i class="material-icons">clear</i></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="btn-group btn-group-xs dropup floating-action-button">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-fab btn-raised dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><i class="material-icons">save</i>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
    <li><a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-fab btn-raised"><i class="material-icons">clear</i></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't say that it is ideal, but the following seems to solve part of your problem.

```
.dropdown-menu {
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    border: none;
}
```

Unfortunately, I was not able to figure out what the `material-icons` class didn't work. Hopefully this answer will help you get closer to a solution.